# unistall Ubuntu when Wubi fails

Tags: wubi, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi on my Windows 7 laptop about a year ago. I hadn't used it for a while until a couple of days ago. I checked for software updates and got a bunch. I began to install them. During this process I opened the Software Center and tried to look at the software that I had currently installed. This seemed to mess up the installation process (the details window began showing a terminal-like display). When it finally finished (after about an hour) I tried to shut it down. But it just hung for about half an hour without any disk activity, so I forced a shut-down by holding the power button. Now when I go into Ubuntu it runs very slowly or not at all. When I try to uninstall it with Wubi it says

“Error executing command

> > command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe/delete{…}\f
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=An error occurred while attempting to delete the specified entry.
> >     The system cannot find the file specified”

Is there any way to delete Ubuntu while leaving my Windows system in place in this situation? Any suggestions very gratefully received.

Comment: Yes there is a way... [How do I manually uninstall Wubi?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F)

Answer (score -1):

there are two checks you can perform to check after it has been removed.

The first one checks that wubi has been uninstalled and this could leave gigbytes of information leftover (use the second check for left over data)

the second check is to open a partition manager and check that the partitoin for ubuntu is gone. you can press start and search partition to do this.

firstly i suggest pressing start, type in uninstall, and then click [Uninstall a program]

when it loads find Wubi within the list, click it and then click uninstall at the top, follow the instructions and restart to perform the check.

the next thing to do is just delete the partition.
like mentioned before, click start, type partiton and click the option labelled [create and format hard disk partitons] at this point remove any cd`s or usb drives and continue.

you will see at the bottom of the window that opens a row, on the left of that row will be the name of the hard disk eg (C:windows) and its normally the C drive unless you changed it. then right click the ubuntu partition (normally the third one along) and click delete partitoin, you can check your deleting the correct one by going into my computer and renaming your first windows partitoin, then re open the window, press f5 to refreash and the one thats renamed is the one you DONT delete. if you have any problems just comment or email me 2340k@live.co.uk